# Entity Framework missing registry value

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017, registrykey

I've recently installed Visual Studio 2017 and trying to do some exercises with Linq queries but during installation of EF package, I saw the following figure and I don't know how to edit the registry to solve this issue. Please give me some advise and I would appreciate your help.

[picture of the Error Message Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuH7E.png)

Comment: is this a new or existing project?

Comment: Please show the exception message *in text*, not as an image. Also tell exactly what you did in the package manager console. This looks like scaffolding a context, not the installation of a NuGet package.

Comment: this is new project on the exciting solution .